# How to check if a integer value has been saved in a float?

Tags: casting, type-conversion, julia

I am reading some data where the output, if numerical, is always stored as Float, and I would like to cleaning it up assigning it an Integer if it is actually possible (e.g. 1.0) or keep the original type if not.

Is using try/catch the best approach ?

```
function convertToIntIfPossible(x)
    try
     return convert(Int64,x)
    catch
        return x
    end
end
anInt   = convertToIntIfPossible(1.0)
aFloat  = convertToIntIfPossible(1.23)
aString = convertToIntIfPossible("aaa")
```

EDIT: This (from crstnbr answer) is much faster:

```
function convertToIntIfPossible2(x)
    if typeof(x) <: Number
        if isinteger(x)
            return convert(Int64,x)
        else
            return x
        end
    else
        return x
    end
end
```

EDIT2: This is even faster (tk Alexander Morley):

```
function convertToIntIfPossible2(x)
    if typeof(x) <: Number
        if (x == trunc(x))
            return Int64(x)
        else
            return x
        end
    else
        return x
    end
end
```

Comment: This might be a _really_ bad idea, and could slow down your code dramatically, if you later use that output for more calculations. Maybe you can explain why you want to do this?

Comment: @DNF this is for the OdsIO.jl package that imports data from ods (e.g. libreoffice) to various Julia containers. I see your point.. if the destination container is a Matrix, it is best to keep all as floats, but if it is a DataFrame, it is better to distinguish between integer and floats columns..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Focusing on the title of your question "How to check if a integer value has been saved in a float?", I would like to give the straight forward answer `isinteger(x)`.

> isinteger(x) -> Bool
>
> Test whether x is numerically equal to some integer.
>
> ```
>   julia> isinteger(4.0)
>   true
> ```

Example:

```
julia> IntInDisguise = 3.0
3.0

julia> ReallyFloat = 3.141
3.141

julia> ReallyInteger = 3
3

julia> isinteger(IntInDisguise)
true

julia> isinteger(ReallyFloat)
false

julia> isinteger(ReallyInteger)
true
```

Comment: This need to be wrapped in a `typeof(x) <: Number` check to avoid  error with non numeric values. Still much faster than my try/catch implementation.

Comment: True. As I wrote, I focused on your title question and there you indicate that x is a float.

Comment: As it happens what I wrote is almost exactly how `isinteger` is implemented in Base...

Answer (score 2):

You *could* create two methods like this:

```
convertToIntIfPossible(x::AbstractFloat) = (x == trunc(x)) ? Int64(x) : x

convertToIntIfPossible(x) = x
```

But the whole thing sounds like not a great idea if possible as performant code in Julia requires [Type Stability](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/performance-tips/#Avoid-changing-the-type-of-a-variable-1).

Do you really want to convert the numbers to integers or do you just want them to be **displayed** without any decimal point. If the latter then I guess there are  more elegant solutions.

Comment: In Julia 0.6 I get the error `syntax: "x<:AbstractFloat" is not a valid function argument name`

Comment: Should probably be `convertToIntIfPossible(x::AbstractFloat)`.

Answer (score 1):

To add to Alexander Morley's comments, here is a more step-wise approach to getting the `convertifpossibletoint` function, which might be more Julian:

```
tryconvert(T, x) = try Nullable{T}(convert(T,x)) catch Nullable{T}() end

convertifpossible(T,x) = get(tryconvert(T,x),x)

convertifpossibletoint(x) = convertifpossible(Int, x)
```

Giving:

```
julia> convertifpossibletoint(1.0)
1

julia> convertifpossibletoint(1.1)
1.1

julia> convertifpossibletoint("abc")
"abc"
```